# Datatables locate row through all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to find a row that has a certain value in one of the cells and apply class. I managed to do that, but problem is that it works only when I get to the page where that value exists.

```
drawCallback: function( settings ) {
    var data = table.rows({ page: 'all' }).data();
    $(data).each( function (idx) {
        var row = table.row( idx );

        if ( row.data().username === 'miko55' ) {
            row.nodes().to$().addClass( 'table-success' );
            alert(idx);
        }
    } );
}
```

I tried with page:'all' but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: please change the tag to `javascript` or `jquery`, and what is `page` here?

Comment: The page modifier allows you to control if the selector should consider all data in the table, regardless of paging, or if only the rows in the currently displayed page should be used.

Comment: Question: are you using client side method or server side method when generate the table using datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Datatables `jumpToData()` [plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()) to achieve this. Try this

```
//jump to particular row in a table
YOUR_TABLE.page.jumpToData('VALUE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR', 0);

//add you CSS class to the row
YOUR_TABLE.rows(function (idx, data, node) {
  if(data.YOUR_VALUE === 'VALUE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR') {
    return true;
  }
}).nodes().to$().addClass('YOUR CSS CLASS');
```

Comment: It's same result, class is added only when I get to the page with value that I am looking for

Comment: did you add the plugin I said to your app? this exact code is working for me

Comment: also for some reason, Datatable CDNs won't work as expected so better include  Datatable and plugin files to your app